# GUI-based client server program?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

Can somebody show me how to write a GUI-based client server program? I have written on each side, but I haven't combined them.

If it is possible, PyQt for GUI and SocketServer for client/server base. I will be very happy, if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Is unclear from what protocol you want to use such of server client application. First I think that is more constructive to see how can be added some graphical interface for an server client project. However, an example is [pyXMLRPCssh](http://pyxmlrpcssh.sourceforge.net/Wikka-1.1.6.5/wikka.php?wakka=HomePage/backlinks). Also, take a look on example of using GTK on [ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2001605).